# Can't connect to samba shares from Ubuntu 18.10, connecting from windows works

Tags: networking, nautilus, samba, 18.10

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.10 as dualboot with my win10. I have a few samba shares running from a linux mint install on my home network, which I can access just fine from Windows (7 and 10) and from another Mint laptop.

However, my fresh ubuntu install just refuses to connect to these shares. It sees them fine, but when I try to log in, it just the login dialog just pops up again in Nautilus, no errors shown. I tried setting "guest ok = yes" in smb.conf, but I still can't connect. I also tried creating another samba user, still no luck.

Samba version 4.3.11 and my conf file is as follows, my one and only share is at the very end, edited the user and sharenames. Thanks!

```
## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
        workgroup = workgroup

# server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
        server string = %h server (Samba, Linux Mint)

#### Networking ####
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0
;   bind interfaces only = yes

#### Debugging/Accounting ####
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 1000
#   syslog only = no
        syslog = 0
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


####### Authentication #######

        server role = standalone server
;       passdb backend = tdbsam
        obey pam restrictions = yes
        unix password sync = yes
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        pam password change = yes
        map to guest = bad user

########## Domains ###########

;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
#   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile
;   logon drive = H:
#   logon home = \\%N\%U
;   logon script = logon.cmd

# This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
# password; please adapt to your needs
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u
; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

############ Misc ############

;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m
;   idmap uid = 10000-20000
;   idmap gid = 10000-20000
;   template shell = /bin/bash
;       usershare max shares = 100
        usershare allow guests = yes
        security = user
;       encrypt passwords = yes
;       guest ok = no
;       guest account = nobody
        username map = /etc/samba/smbusers

#======================= Share Definitions =======================


;[homes]
;   comment = Home Directories
;   browseable = no
;   read only = yes
;   create mask = 0700
;   directory mask = 0700
;   valid users = %S
;[netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
    read only = yes

;[profiles]
;   comment = Users profiles
;   path = /home/samba/profiles
;   guest ok = no
;   browseable = no
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700

[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        browseable = no
        path = /var/spool/samba
        printable = yes
;       guest ok = no
;       read only = yes
        create mask = 0700


[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/printers
;       browseable = yes
;       read only = yes
;       guest ok = no
;   write list = root, @lpadmin

[My LAN share name]
        path = /media/myshare/etcetcetc
        writeable = yes
;       browseable = yes
        valid users = myuser, myuser2
```

Comment: Is Smb4K installed on you computer?

Comment: Nope, only what came with 18.10, it's a relatively fresh install (2 days old)

Comment: You can install it from ubuntu repository that comes along with 18.10 - if it does no good, it does not harm either. I think it can help you see the shares. This is how I could see my remote printer without any configuring. Before installing Smb4K, I was unable to install that printer.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help :( I just tried mounting from command line too, with sudo mount -t cifs -o user=myuser '//192.168.1.150/My Share' ./Share, but it returns with an error: mount error(13): Permission denied. After that I tried adding sec=ntlm, then it returns with mount error(22): Invalid argument. Installed cifs-utils, but no help.

Comment: In your script, maybe you should uncomment the last ";       browseable = yes", that's to say remove the ";" before "browseable = yes".

Comment: Tried that just now, no change, same errors from CLI and same nautilus behavior. Server is running Mint 18.2 if that makes a difference.